# Solve equation system for expression

Tags: equation-solving

How to solve this equations and find specified expression (all integers)?

```
x * N + y = 2012
y * N + x = 2011
x + y = ?
```

I've tried but got formulas as an answer instead of a number.

Comment: `x + y /. Solve[{x*n + y == 2012, y*n + x == 2011, x > 0, n > 0, y > 0}, {x, n, y}, Integers]` ?

Comment: `N` is a function, use `n` or `NN` or something else. Use `==`, not `=`.

Comment: Don't understand the output, does it have more than one solution?

Comment: It does not work in wolframalpha?

Comment: Perhaps `Solve[{x*n + y == 2012, y*n + x == 2011, z == x + y}, {x, y, z, 
  n}, Integers]` shows the two solutions more clearly.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think that WolframAlpha is so different from Mathematics

Comment: This `solve {x*z+y==2012, y*z+x==2011, w==x+y} over the integers` works in WolframAlpha, finds both solutions, and gives you the sum of x and y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the capital `N` is reserved in Mathematica, and its use as a variable is illegal. Use small `n` instead.

Try this:

```
eqn = {x*n + y == 2012, y*n + x == 2011, x + y == z};

Solve[eqn, {x, y, z}]



  (*  {{x -> -((2011 - 2012 n)/(-1 + n^2)), 
      y -> -((2012 - 2011 n)/(-1 + n^2)), z -> 4023/(1 + n)}}  *)
```

or this:

```
Eliminate[eqn, {x, y}]

(*  (1 + n) z == 4023  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Second option works even in WolframAlpha, thanks. But it gives also negative numbers, how to specify n > 0?

Comment: Your last question is unclear. Indeed, in your main question, you asked to find `x+y`. That is `z` in my solution. The only thing left is to only use in this formula positive `n` values. Therefore, I do not understand your question in the comment.